# Retrieving data from database on string match and skip the repeating values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have big database of million of photos. It contains a field named "Place" that contains location information (i.e. town, province, city, country etc) for every photo in Db as shown:

```
56461972:MetroTuria:POI,20220221:Olivereta:Suburb,776688:Valencia:Town,12602139:Valencia:Province,12578038:Valencia:AutonomousCommunity,20080321:46018:Zip,23424950:**Spain:Country**,56043644:Europe%2FMadrid:Timezone
```

I am interested in retrieving all the country names found in it and may be return them in a different table. And just skip where country name repeats. This way I shall have an idea of the countries where photos were taken. 
So, something like where this text  i.e. ":Country" is found it retrieves the country name associated with it and add it in a new table.

It is bit difficult to explain. Hope it make sense.

Thanks in Advance.

*Some updates for response:

```
56558566:Duval+Street:Suburb,2432044:Key+West:Town,12587846:Monroe:County,2347568:Florida:State,12772085:33040:Zip,23424977:United+States:Country,56043648:America%2FNew_York:Timezone  
56574535:Columbus+Park:Suburb,2496012:South+Boston:Suburb,2367105:Boston:Town,12588712:Suffolk:County,2347580:Massachusetts:State,12758726:02127:Zip,23424977:United+States:Country,56043648:America%2FNew_York:Timezone    
1984273:Artybash:Town,2120895:GornoAltaysk:Town,12597718:Turochakskiy+Raion:District,20070530:Altai+Republic:Province,24553375:649:Zip,23424936:Russia:Country,56043608:Asia%2FOmsk:Timezone
```

And Please I just want them to retrieved once. e.g. If "Spain" is associated with many images so it should be considered once only. My whole purpose is just to see total number and name of countries where images are taken.

Please mind I am just a beginner to SQL.

Comment: I would absolutely recommend doing some normalization on the `Place` field. You're already seeing the trouble you have to go through to just find the country. Initial setup will take some significant effort, but you do seem to be on the right track here.

Comment: Are the asterisks around the Country in your string or did you add them for effect?

Comment: @Shawn I added for effect.

Comment: What do the elements in the string mean? Are these comma-delimited lists? ie does `56461972:MetroTuria:POI` go together as one element? So each element is like `<number>:<value>:<fieldName>`? It's definitely possible to push these fields into their own normalized tables. It would take a lot of processing and would absolutely need to be done in down-time.

Comment: And what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to extract the country, you can use:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(place, ':Country', 1), ':', -1)
```

The inner `substring_index()` extracts the portion before country.  That is a long string at ends with `' . . . Zip,23424950:**Spain'`.  The outer `substring_index()` takes everything after the final colon, which is the name of the country.

[Here](http://rextester.com/LKMK28283) is a rextester.

EDIT:

If you want a count by country, then:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(place, ':Country', 1), ':', -1) as country,
       count(*)
from t
group by country;
```

Comment: Tried this query but it returns an empty result. Can not identify why?

Comment: @Meana . . . I had lower case "country", so if your collation is case sensitive, that could be the cause.  Otherwise, your string does not look the way you say that it does.

Comment: I already tried with upper case also as per field name. May be I should send you more records from Place field. Please find updations in question itself.

Comment: The query says empty results, but on the other hand it send the "Timezone" in the new table where I was returning result. Can You have look please as it seems like reading "Timezone" word from all records.

Comment: ...Ok. Please have look at my command then. Possibly i am making some mistake:`INSERT INTO Countries3(Place) 
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(Place, ':country', 1), ':', -1)
 FROM Countries2 
`

Comment: @Meana . . . I added a Rextester to the question so you can see the code work on the data you added into your question.

Comment: ...I agree...your results are desired ones. Thankful for your effort.  But can not see why not working for me :(

Comment: @Gordon...could not understand the strange behavior why it did not worked earlier. But it just working now like a charm ...successfully extracted country info. Thanks alottttt!

Answer (score 0):

To get the count for each country, you can use:

```
SELECT s1.theCountry, count(*) AS theCount
FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(place, ':Country', 1),':',-1) AS theCountry
  FROM photos
) s1
GROUP BY s1.theCountry
```

Comment: @Shawn..Thanks shawn for your support too! :)